# How to send a variable whose name I don't know in the view?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to create a website using codeigniter. I have two tables in the database. Theses tables are Category(Category Name, Category_Id) and Item(Item_Name, Category_id). Now, in my view I want of show the items in different tables for the different categories.

So far, I have come up with this, but obviously it is not working. The code in the model is this.

```
$query = 'select category_id as id, category_name as name from category;';
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $data['category'] = $result->result_array();
    foreach($data['category'] as $d)
    {
        $query = "select item_name as name from item where item_catagory_id = '{$d['id']}';";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        $data["{$d['id']}"] = $result->result_array();
    }
    $this->load->view('view', $data);
```

The code in the view is like this.

```
<?php foreach($category as $c):?>
            <h2><?php echo $c['name']; ?></h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item Name</td>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach($c['id'] as $d): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $d['name'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </table>
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

But it says that " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". It also says that the error is in this line :

```
<?php foreach($c['id'] as $d): ?>
```

Comment: Not sure why you need to know the name of the view as it seems to be executing anyway. You have 2 foreach statements, which one are you getting the error on? Have you tried a print_r on $category and $c to find what they contain?

Comment: @CaptainPayalytic I am having error in the nested foreach loop.

Comment: I am really sorry, i don't understand what you mean by "Not sure why you need to know the name of the view as it seems to be executing anyway". I just named the view as view here. In my actual code it is named as something else.

Comment: Your question is: "How to send a variable in the view whose name I don't know?" I am not clear why knowing the name of the view is relevant to your question.

Comment: The `Invalid argument...` error simply means that the `foreach` did not receive an array. Before you send the `$data` array to the view try to find out what is in it (e.g. `var_dump($data);die;`).

Comment: @CaptainPayalytic, Its the name of the variable, whose name I dont know, not the view.

Comment: English as php has syntax and semantics. Your question is constructed such that its meaning is as I suggested. As with programming, you have to be careful of statement construction in order to ensure that what you say is what you mean.

Comment: So have you done the print_r() statements that I asked about? If so can we see the results?

Comment: print_r in $category shows : Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => asdf ) )

Comment: print_r in $c shows : 1

Comment: If there is no data in the item table, then will it show this error? @CaptainPayalytic

Comment: So the value of $c['id'] is 1 and that is not an array and that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: hmm, thanks. I think i will try some different approach. Thanks for the help. @CaptainPayalytic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to accomplish, Then here's what you want:

Change

```
$data["{$d['id']}"] = $result->result_array();
```

To:

```
$d['items'] = $result->result_array();
```

Then in your view, you'll simply do the second foreach like this:

```
<?php foreach($c['items'] as $d): ?>
```

This way you're adding the items to the category itself with a known key.